# Heroku build fails due to missing module

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

After many successful builds, I'm suddenly getting a build error whenever my Node app deploys to Heroku. I am getting build failed errors that say

```
2018-10-07T20:40:50.484403+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-10-07T20:41:10.730943+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node ./index.js`
2018-10-07T20:41:15.939290+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-10-07T20:41:15.958229+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-10-07T20:41:15.841898+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:487
2018-10-07T20:41:15.841925+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2018-10-07T20:41:15.841926+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-10-07T20:41:15.841927+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-07T20:41:15.841935+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'sax'
2018-10-07T20:41:15.841942+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
2018-10-07T20:41:15.841949+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
2018-10-07T20:41:15.841951+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
2018-10-07T20:41:15.841952+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
2018-10-07T20:41:15.841958+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/xml2js/lib/parser.js:9:9)
2018-10-07T20:41:15.841960+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/xml2js/lib/parser.js:357:4)
2018-10-07T20:41:15.841961+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
2018-10-07T20:41:15.841962+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
2018-10-07T20:41:15.841964+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
2018-10-07T20:41:15.841965+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
2018-10-07T20:41:15.841966+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
2018-10-07T20:41:15.841968+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
2018-10-07T20:41:15.841969+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
2018-10-07T20:41:15.841972+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:37:4)
2018-10-07T20:41:15.841971+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:12:12)
```

These are my package.json dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.0.6",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.315.0",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^3.6.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-router": "0.0.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "frontend": "file:client",
    "graphql": "^0.13.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.14",
    "multer": "^1.3.1",
    "multer-s3": "^2.7.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.3"
  }
```

I am assuming sax is a dependency of one of my dependencies. I've tried destroying this application and redeploying, I've tried verifying my versions and compatibility (to the best of my knowledge). The app was running fine for the first 50 or so deploys but then suddenly started throwing these errors and nothing in my application (that I can see) has changed aside from my actual code (mostly frontend). No dependency changes or anything like that has changed since it was last working.

All of my dependencies are in the dependencies object in my package.json (only thing in devDependencies is nodemon).  One thing I thought about today but not sure if it's the cause or even related (though it does seem relevant enough that it's worth mentioning) I have been having a lot of package-lock.json conflicts with git. My buddy and I are working on this and both push/pull from the same repo (he does the frontend/react stuff and I focus on the backend). But every pull from his changes have caused package-lock conflicts and same for him when I push changes (we're both running the same version of npm and node). Again I am not sure if that's part of this issue but it seems oddly coincidental.

Comment: If you do `npm ls sax` you can see the dependency graph. Do you have a public git repo to share?

Comment: Is `sax` present in your `package.lock` or `yarn.lock`?

Comment: @chris it's a dependency of one of the packages I added not one I directly use. I did try to install it into my package.json last night but it didn't help

Comment: @crescentfresh, that's not what I asked. _Is it in your lockfile?_ Is your lockfile tracked? Heroku will install those locked down packages, not the loosely-defined top-level dependencies in your `package.json`.

Comment: @Chris ah! my apologies, misread it. It's present in my package-lock for AWS-SDK  as well as for many other packages.

Comment: @crescentfresh, and the lockfile is included in your Git repository? It gets pushed to Heroku?

Comment: @Chris yeah it's there and using "stat package-lock.json" it was last modified today when I tried another deployment.